# Have trouble reducing $\frac{(a + c)^2 - b^2}{4a^2c^2 - (a^2 + c^2 - b^2)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I'm trying to reduce the below equation but I'm kind of stuck. This is what I have done so far.
\begin{align*}
\frac{(a + c)^2 - b^2}{4a^2c^2 - (a^2 + c^2 - b^2)^2} & = \frac{(a + c - b) (a + c + b)}{4a^2c^2 - a^4 - 2a^2c^2 + 2a^2b^2 - c^4 + 2b^2c^2 - b^4}\\
& = \frac{(a + c - b) (a + c + b)}{2a^2c^2 - a^4 - + 2a^2b^2 - c^4 + 2b^2c^2 - b^4}\\
& = \frac{(a + c - b) (a + c + b)}{a^2(2c^2 - a^2 + 2b^2) + b^2(2c^2 - b^2) - c^4}
\end{align*}

This equation seems to grow bigger and bigger, and I'm not able to reduce it. Did I do something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, you did something wrong. The given expression has lots of *structure*. By multiplying out you are destroying visual structure. The bottom is a difference of two squares. Exploit that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice the denominator is the difference of two squares just like the numerator. Indeed,

$$\color{Red}{4a^2c^2}-\color{Blue}{(a^2+c^2-b^2)^2}=\left(\color{Red}{2ac}-\color{Blue}{(a^2+c^2-b^2)}\right)\left(\color{Red}{2ac}+\color{Blue}{(a^2+c^2-b^2)}\right).$$

Now use $(a\pm c)^2=\color{Blue}{a^2}\pm \color{Red}{2ac}+\color{Blue}{c^2}$ and then do a simple cancellation.